# React Native PanGesture set pan position from tap

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently working on an HSV-Colorpicker component for a react-native project I have. I have everything setup so that I have a draggable object on the HSV-canvas and a slider next to it to handle the hue change.

However, I now want to be able to set the position of the draggable object by clicking on the hsv-canvas. I got it working so that the draggable element moves to the right position, however, when I then try to drag the element with a pan-gesture again, the offset for the pan-gesture starts from the wrong position.

Here is the corresponding parts of code:

```
setPanFromTouch(event) {
    const x = event.nativeEvent.locationX;
    const y = event.nativeEvent.locationY;
    const gesture = {
        moveX: x,
        moveY: y
    };
    this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: x, y: y });
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.updateColorFromGesture((gesture as any));
}
//inside the render method those are the 2 components that respond to 
//touches and pans
//Parent container for the HSV-hue and the draggable element 
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        style={{
        width: this.props.colorBoxWidth,
        height: this.props.height
    }}
    onPress={this.setPanFromTouch}
>
<Animated.View
    {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
    style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), {
    height: this.draggableSize,
    width: this.draggableSize,
    borderRadius: this.draggableSize / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1
    }]}>
</Animated.View>
//pan-gesture setup inside the constructor method
(this as any).panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: () => {
            this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: this.state.panValues.x, y: this.state.panValues.y });
            this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        },
        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
            dx: this.state.pan.x,
            dy: this.state.pan.y
        }]),
        onPanResponderRelease: (e: GestureResponderEvent, gesture: PanResponderGestureState) => {
                this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
                this.updateColorFromGesture(gesture);
        }
    });
//component will mount code
componentWillMount() {
    this.state.pan.addListener((c) => this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        panValues: c
    }));
}
```

I know that inside the `onPanResponderGrant` I am resetting the offset again, however this is necessary for the dragging to work correctly. I also tried to set the new values for `this.state.panValues.x` and `this.state.panValues.y` after updating the pan position from the touch event but setState does not change the behavior at all.

This is what the colorpicker looks like:

[image: colorpicker result]

I would be really grateful if someone has an idea what I could do in this situation. Let me know if you need more code or anything else. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a normal instance variable instead of the state for detecting if a pan position was set by a touch. Here is what I did:

```
//At the top of my react component
private setFromTouch = false;
//in the onPanResponderGrant method of the PanResponder.create inside
//the constructor
...
onPanResponderGrant: () => {
    if (!this.setFromTouch) {
        this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: this.state.panValues.x, y: 
        this.state.panValues.y });
    } else {
        this.setFromTouch = false;
    }
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
}
...
//New setFromTouch() method
setPanFromTouch(event) {
    const x = event.nativeEvent.locationX;
    const y = event.nativeEvent.locationY;
    const gesture = {
        moveX: x,
        moveY: y
    };
    this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: x, y: y });
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.setFromTouch = true;
    this.updateColorFromGesture((gesture as any));
}
```